# JSON Formatter to Swift Struct to Parsing

Tags: json, swift

I'm at a loss right now of how to properly convert my JSON file to Swift Struct then parse it accordingly. I cant seem to parse the retrieved data. When running a print statement in the do-try-catch block of my JSONDecoder, it catches an error during parsing.

My questions are:

1. Did I format my Structs correctly?
2. Am I missing something in my method?

See below for details...

Appreciate the help!

**Here's a snippet of my JSON**

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "day": 1,
        "image": {
            "attribution": "© YouVersion",
            "url": "//imageproxy-cdn.youversionapi.com/{width}x{height},png/https://s3.amazonaws.com/static-youversionapi-com/images/base/10778/1280x1280.jpg"
        },
        "verse": {
            "human_reference": "Proverbs 16:9",
            "html": null,
            "text": "A man’s heart plans his course, but Yahweh directs his steps.",
            "url": "https://www.bible.com/bible/206/PRO.16.9",
            "usfms": [
                "PRO.16.9"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "day": 2,
        "image": {
            "attribution": "© YouVersion",
            "url": "//imageproxy-cdn.youversionapi.com/{width}x{height},png/https://s3.amazonaws.com/static-youversionapi-com/images/base/27119/1280x1280.jpg"
        },
        "verse": {
            "human_reference": "Psalms 90:12",
            "html": null,
            "text": "So teach us to count our days, that we may gain a heart of wisdom.",
            "url": "https://www.bible.com/bible/206/PSA.90.12",
            "usfms": [
                "PSA.90.12"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "day": 3,
        "image": {
            "attribution": "© YouVersion",
            "url": "//imageproxy-cdn.youversionapi.com/{width}x{height},png/https://s3.amazonaws.com/static-youversionapi-com/images/base/27117/1280x1280.jpg"
        },
        "verse": {
            "human_reference": "Proverbs 16:3",
            "html": null,
            "text": "Commit your deeds to Yahweh, and your plans shall succeed.",
            "url": "https://www.bible.com/bible/206/PRO.16.3",
            "usfms": [
                "PRO.16.3"
            ]
        }
   ]
```

}

**Here's my resulting Struct(s)**

```
struct VerseData: Codable {

var data: [Datum]
}

struct Datum: Codable {

let day: Int
let image: VerseImageData
let verse: VerseDetails

}

struct VerseImageData: Codable {

var attribution: String?
var url: String = ""
}

struct VerseDetails: Codable {

var humanReference: String = ""
var url: String = ""
var text: String = ""

}
```

**Here's my call in my VC.Swift**

```
func getData() {
    
    let urlStr = URL(string: "https://developers.youversionapi.com/1.0/verse_of_the_day?version_id=206")
    
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urlStr!)
    request.setValue("myAPIKey", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-YouVersion-Developer-Token")
    request.addValue("en", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    print(request)
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        
    guard let data = data else { return }
        
        do {
            let verseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(VerseData.self, from: data)
            print(verseData)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
     }
    dataTask.resume()
  }
}
```

Comment: seems everything good

Comment: try to print error

Comment: `print("erro\(error)")`

Comment: @jawadAli - error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "humanReference", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "verse", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"humanReference\", intValue: nil) (\"humanReference\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: @jawadAli Okay so I got it. "humanReference? should be "human_reference" according to the JSON and API documentation. Noob mistake on my hand!

Comment: Can i post answer ?

Comment: @jawadAli yes go ahead please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print error
"`humanReference`"? should be "`human_reference`" according to the JSON and `API documentation`